# quartz Scheduler with spring MVC without using maven

Tags: spring

I am using tomcat version 7.0. My requirement is that when tomcat starts up, I would like to start a QuartzScheduler which will schedule some jobs at a regular interval. 

can any one give me a best example for my problem using a ContextListener  (This might be a clean approach to start the scheduler inside the contextInitialized method and shutdown the scheduler inside contextDestroyed method) or any other methods .

***Note : without using MAVEN**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can very well implement a ServletContextListener (QuartzTestListener) and add this listener in a Web Xml file something like below

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>com.test.QuartzTestListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

wherein you implement contextInitialized methods something like below:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent ctx) {
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzJob.class)
    .withIdentity("testJobName", "test1").build();

     try{
      Scheduler   scheduler = ((StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getServletContext().getAttribute(QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY)).getScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, new CronTrigger(...));    
    }catch(SchedulerException e){
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also make use `QuartzInitializerListener` .